# Cygwin dd of='\\.\PhysicalDrive0' Invalid argument

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I'm trying to copy my hard drive. `unxutils` dd that used to work before, now doesn't.

So I'm trying the Cygwin version. It reads just fine, but can't open for writing:

```
$ dd if='\\.\PhysicalDrive0' count=0
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 4.4131e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s

$ dd if=/dev/null of='\\.\PhysicalDrive0'
dd: opening `\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0': Invalid argument
```

Comment: Have you tried [this native version](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) of dd?

Comment: Windows also writes zeros to a partition when doing a full format. This behavior has been implemented [starting with Windows Vista](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941961).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc
```

where sdc is whole drive that you want to be zeroed.
Check that you are sure that you are zeroing right drive.
sdc is the third whole drive,
sdc2 is the second partition on the third drive (contains boot sector if it is there).
Cygwin uses standard *nix terminology for local drives.
You may want to use `pv` (pipe viewer, it is available in Cygwin) to see the progress:

```
pv /dev/zero > /dev/sdc
```

Comment: **Windows** has a /dev/zero and a /dev/sdc ?

Comment: Cygwin on Windows - yes, it has.

Comment: Cool. I really need to read Cygwin's documentation.

Comment: Now if only they ported `cfdisk`

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
dd if=/dev/null of='\\.\PhysicalDrive0' conv=notrunc,nocreat
```

**Upd**: Cygwin has an alias `/dev/sda` for `PhysicalDrive0` and so forth and opening it like this does not require conv flags

Comment: You're reading from /dev/null, which should do nothing...

Comment: This opens a file for writing. Enough for a test

Comment: @basin /dev/null immediately ends, shouldn't be used here.